# Trying to use Firebase Authentication link to the Firebase Database (Update the data based on the ID)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Currently, I store the email and password in Firebase uthentication. Other than that, all the user's detail except the email and password will be stored in Firebase Database. I'm now trying to do for updating phone number from Firebase Database. Anyone can help me solve the problem because I stuck at here such a long time already. Here's my code:

```
public class ChangeEmailPassword extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnChangeEmail, btnChangePassword,
        changeEmail, changePassword, back, btnChangePhone, btnChangeCarPlate, changePhone,
        changeCarPlate, signOut;

private EditText oldEmail, newEmail, password, newPassword, oldPhone, newPhone, confirmPassword;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private FirebaseUser user;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private String txtPhone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_email_password);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //get firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //get current user
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {
                // user auth state is changed - user is null
                // launch login activity
                startActivity(new Intent(ChangeEmailPassword.this, TestUser.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    btnChangeEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_email_button);
    btnChangePassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_password_button);
    btnChangePhone=(Button)findViewById(R.id.change_phone_button);
    changeEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeEmail);
    changePassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changePass);
    changePhone=(Button) findViewById(R.id.changePhone);
    back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnback1);

    oldEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.old_email);
    newEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    newPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPassword);
    confirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.confirmpassword);
    oldPhone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.old_phone);
    newPhone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_phone);


    oldEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    newEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    newPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    confirmPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    changeEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    changePassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    oldPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    newPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    if (progressBar != null) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ChangeEmailPassword.this, TestUser.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    btnChangeEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            oldEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            confirmPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changeEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            changePassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changePhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            oldPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    changeEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (user != null && !newEmail.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                user.updateEmail(newEmail.getText().toString().trim())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(ChangeEmailPassword.this, "Email address is updated. Please sign in with new email id!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(ChangeEmailPassword.this, MainActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(ChangeEmailPassword.this, "Failed to update email!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } else if (newEmail.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                newEmail.setError("Enter email");
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    btnChangePassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            oldEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            confirmPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            changeEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changePassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            changePhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            oldPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    changePassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (user != null && !newPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                if (newPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() < 6) {
                    newPassword.setError("Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters");
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (!(newPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals(confirmPassword.getText().toString().trim()))) {
                    newPassword.setError("Password are not matching");
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    user.updatePassword(newPassword.getText().toString().trim())
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(ChangeEmailPassword.this, "Password is updated, sign in with new password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(ChangeEmailPassword.this, MainActivity.class));
                                        finish();                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(ChangeEmailPassword.this, "Failed to update password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            } else if (newPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                newPassword.setError("Enter password");
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    btnChangePhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            oldEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            confirmPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changeEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changePassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changePhone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            oldPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newPhone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });


    changePhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtPhone = newPhone.getText().toString().trim();
//if the user is not null and the txtPhone equals "" as well as the ID is not empty, it will update the user's mobile phone
        if (user != null && !txtPhone.equals("")) {
        if (!(TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getUid()))) {
                updateUser(txtPhone);
            }
        else if (newPhone.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            newPhone.setError("Enter phone number");
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        }
    }});

private void updateUser(String phone)
{
    Account acc=new Account();
    acc.set_Phone(Integer.valueOf(phone));
    mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).setValue(phone);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
```

But why it shows me the NullException

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.google.online_mobile_flexi_parking, PID: 12909
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.google.online_mobile_flexi_parking.ChangeEmailPassword.updateUser(ChangeEmailPassword.java:362)
                  at com.google.online_mobile_flexi_parking.ChangeEmailPassword.access$1200(ChangeEmailPassword.java:33)
                  at com.google.online_mobile_flexi_parking.ChangeEmailPassword$8.onClick(ChangeEmailPassword.java:237)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18440)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5028)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The screenshot that I captured from the Firebase Authentication and Firebase Database:

- Firebase Authentication including the email, password and ID

[image: Firebase Authentication including the email, password and ID]

- Firebase Database including all the user's details and the ID which is from Firebase Authentication

[image: Firebase Database including all the user's details and the ID which is from Firebase Authentication]

Comment: Can you please tell us which is line 362 in your code where there is exception ?

Comment: @AbhinavPuri line 362 is mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).setValue(phone);

Comment: Seems like either mDatabase, or, user, or, mDatabase.child() is null. Please log these values and check what is null ?

Comment: ya it cannot show any result, could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked which of those values are null ?